# WPF Custom lasso selector?

Tags: wpf, selection, inkcanvas

How can I implement a custom lasso selector on an `InkCanvas`? How do I detect involved inks or elements by collecting points generated by mouse movement?

Answer (score 1):

1. No need to implement lasso selector. **InkCanvas** with **EditingMode="Select"** lets you select, move and resize elements on the **InkCanvas**.
2. The ink strokes that user draws on the **InkCanvas** are held in **Strokes** property in the **InkCanvas** element